# Where is SQLite in Xampp?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, xampp

The reason I am asking this is because I have phpLiteadmin giving me a different version than the one on the Xampp Shell. And I can't find either one at all. I have phpLiteadmin here xampp/htdocs/phpliteadmin.php I don't know where phpLiteadmin or the Xampp shell pull this info from. Both of these versions are creating databases in the htdocs folder with the extension .db [image: phpliteadmin sql version]

[image: xampp shell version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, ... SQLite is natively present inside php. SQLite classes available in php language are available in php versions `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)`. You see different versions due to the fact that the php.ini loaded from cli is different from the one loaded from web server.

To find sqlite of your php try this from cli:

```
php -i | grep sqlite --color
```

PS. `--color` highlight the `sqlite` string

To do the same create a php file with this content:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

It will generate an output with current php configuration (from the point of view of your web server). Here you'll find the path of the loaded sqlite command.

Hope this help you.